# Change the author name order in Biblatex APA style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I'm trying to recreate a very specific style based off of Benjamins style, with a few changes. Benjamins is close to APA, but has some small differences, and the supervisor for this project has other idiosyncrasies she has picked up over her years of editing. I am hoping to use the APA style and make these modifications 'on the fly' as it were.

By default, it looks like the biblatex package constructs the bibliography reference with the author of the citation as 'family-given' and all following authors as 'given-family.' Unfortunately, when I use the APA style, all authors change to 'family-given.' I can't figure out how to stop this from happening. Can anyone help me with this?

Simplified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    dashed=false
 ]{biblatex}
\if@pdfa
  \usepackage[a-3b]{pdfx}
\fi
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page             = {},
  pages            = {},
} 

%RENEW APA
% argument meanings from apa.bbx
% #1 = family name
% #2 = given name
% #3 = given name (initials)
% #4 = name prefix
% #5 = name suffix

\renewbibmacro*{name:apa:family-given}[5]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim:apa:family-given}{#4#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#4#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{%
       \mkbibnameprefix{#4}\isdot%
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#5}{}{\addcomma\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#5}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim:apa:family-given}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#4}}}
       {}
       {\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{%
       \bibnamedelimc\mkbibnameprefix{#4}%
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
\ifdefvoid{#5}{}{\addcomma\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#5}\isdot}}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:apa:given-family}[5]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#4#1#5}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#4#1#5}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot%
                   \bibnamedelimd}%
  \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{%
    \mkbibnameprefix{#4}\isdot
    \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot%
  \ifdefvoid{#5}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#5}\isdot}}


\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Test DocumOverleaf Examplent},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen
    }

\title{Testing}
\date{2023}

\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}

%\include{Test.tex}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\nocite{*}   %Uncomment if you have a bibliography with work read but not cited
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nty]
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{refcontext}
\bigskip


\end{document}
```

With APA style included:

```
Epps, Patience L., Webster, Anthony K., & Woodbury, Anthony C. (2017). A holistic
humanities of speaking: Franz Boas and the continuing centrality of texts.
International Journal of American Linguistics, 83 (1), 41–78. https://doi.org/
10.1086/689547
```

Without APA style included:

```
[50] Patience L. Epps, Anthony K. Webster, and Anthony C. Woodbury.
“A Holistic Humanities of Speaking: Franz Boas and the Continuing
Centrality of Texts”. In: International Journal of American Linguistics
83.1 (2017), 41–78. doi: 10.1086/689547. eprint: https://doi.org/
10.1086/689547. url: https://doi.org/10.1086/689547.
```

I would like the style of the first, but only the order of the first name in the list should change, not all of them. In other words:

```
Epps, Patience L.,  Anthony K. Webster, & Anthony C. Woodbury (2017). A holistic
humanities of speaking: Franz Boas and the continuing centrality of texts.
International Journal of American Linguistics, 83 (1), 41–78. https://doi.org/
10.1086/689547.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Aren't the options `style=apa` and `citestyle=authoryear` mutually incompatible? The claim that "the authoryear citestyle in biblatex will sort the first author of the citation as 'family-given' and all following authors as 'given-family'" doesn't sound right; a `citestyle` option should affect how names are displayed in a citation call-out, *not* how they are displayed in the formatted bibliography. The instruction `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` shouldn't be necessary unless your TeX distribution is seriously obsolete. The `\inputencoding{utf8}` instruction seems suspect.

Comment: `biblatex-apa` wasn't really built to be combined with other styles, so `style=apa, citestyle=authoryear,` may or may not work properly at all. Can you explain why you need/want that combination. `biblatex-apa` was developed specifically to implement APA requirements, as such it was not really built with customisability in mind, so it can be tricky to change even small things that "should be easy".

Comment: Oh, both of you are right. It looks like citestyle is absolutely not necessary here, and the differences were coming from the default being overridden by the APA style. I can remove the citestyle command entirely. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue, but it does mean I can keep looking for culprits.

Comment: If you can explain what exactly you want (so far I gather you want APA style, but you want the name format of the authors/primary names in a slightly different order), we might be able to help you.

Comment: I've got most of the edits made I think, the ordering of the authors is the big one I am still trying to fix. I have made some overrides to show full names instead of abbreviating the first initial, and she would also like to add in the publishing city (like it was in older versions of APA). For in text citations, I have changed it to use a colon instead of ', p.' for page identification in-text citations, and I'm working on changing in-text citations containing two publications from the same author to condense from (Author, Year1; Author, Year2) to (Author, Year1 & Year2).

Comment: OK. Let's focus on one thing here: The author ordering. Can you quickly explain what your modification of `name:apa:family-given` and `name:apa:given-family` are doing. Are they here to deal with the name order thing or do they do something different?

Comment: Those two edits are to stop the first name from being shortened to a one letter initial. I have changed the #3 in the original code to a #2 in mine. I was hoping that biblatex would figure out when to use 'family-given' and when to use 'given-family', but right now only the first one is being used.

Comment: I really think you should be working with a plain `authoryear` style rather than the actual `apa` style. You haven't given the full requirements of your style here, but it seems that something like `\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-comp,minnames=99,maxnames=99,articlein=false]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\finalnamedelim{ \& }
\renewcommand\bibpagespunct{,}
\renewcommand\postnotedelim{:}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page             = {},
  pages            = {},
} ` would do most of what you're asking.

Comment: Remember that most people use the term "APA style" to mean a their idea of an author-year style, rather than the actual APA style, in the same way that people use "kleenex" to mean a paper tissue. So if they don't want conforming APA, then you should build off of one of the basic author-year styles rather than the `apa` style.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, `biblatex-apa` implements the complex requirements of APA style. It was not written with customisability in mind. Even changes that look small and "should be easy" can be tricky to pull off. It is therefore often better to base a custom style on a `biblatex` standard style rather than `biblatex-apa`.

If the only thing you need to change are the name format and the colon, the following might be viable. (Changing the name format like this may disable some of the more obscure features of APA style involving names, but you can probably live with that. In any case, check the output carefully.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style=apa,
  dashed=false
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNameAlias{apaauthor}{family-given/given-family}
\DeclareNameAlias{apanames}{given-family}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin}

\autocite[380]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: Aksın, Özge, Hayati Türkmen, Levent Artok, Bekir C¸etinkaya, Chaoying Ni, Orhan Büyükgüngör, & Erhan Özkal (2006). Sigfridsson, Emma & Ulf Ryde (1998).]